# In Reporting Services I have 2 datasets that share a parameter name. Can I Pass a different value to each dataset for this parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report that has 2 charts in it. Each chart has its own dataset with a different stored procedure. These 2 stored procedure share a common parameter name in this case. Is there any way to pass a different value for this parameter to each dataset, or a workaround?

As these procedures are called elsewhere I do not want to change the parameter name in either. I could copy one of the procedures, rename it and one of the parameters, but that also does not seem quite ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[I started typing the answer below then saw that you are on 2005. It was a while ago, but I think there is similar functionality to what I describe below in 2005. But if you are doing much report development 2008 (or better, 2008R2) are massively improved. ]*

Not hard: In Business Intelligence Development Studio, open your report, then right click on the dataset for your SP. In the resulting "Dataset Properties" dialog, you can choose the Parameters pane on the left side. Leave Parameter Name set to the name that the SP requires, but set the "Parameter Value" to whatever parameter or value the SP should be getting from your report.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly was I was looking for. I should add that after I set the values here, I had to make sure to remove the parameter from the list of Report Parameters since the value had already been specified